# Linux - Traffic Engineering

Tags: linux, nat, route, ospf

I have a Linux box with 8 network interfaces:

- 3 interfaces are connected to 3 different ISPs, one interface is the default gw interface.
- Use NAT for outgoing packages.
- Internally, I use the dynamic routing protocol.

When I receive external traffic from a specific interface, I want the outgoing packet to follow and exit the correct interface.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: I would like any traffic entering from an external interface to go to the destination from the same interface regardless of what is indicated in the routing table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iptables` to do so.  The specific command will of course vary on exactly what you want to do, but this answers the broad question as you have it!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that using `iptables` and `iproute2`. But in a case such as yours, with that amount of network interfaces and OSPF, I would rather invest some money in a network router or gateway appliance for the sake of manageability on the long run.

Here's an article that shows an example of how doing so, although it doesn't contemplate OSPF:

https://www.dicas-l.com.br/arquivo/roteamento_avancado_com_iproute2_e_iptables_no_slackware.php

(It is in Portuguese, but focus on the script)

Basically, you should mark packets when they enter your network in `iptables`, and route them using that mark using `iproute2`.

Best regards.